# How to install LibreOffice 4.4.x in Ubuntu?

Tags: libreoffice

Tried:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4
```

but cannot add PPA:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~libreoffice/ubuntu/libreoffice-4-4'.
The team named '~libreoffice' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/libreoffice-4-4'
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Libreoffice 4.4 was just released - the corresponding repository was created just some hours ago, it seems. As a result, the mentioned commands work now:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4
sudo apt-get update                                    
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
[...]
The following packages will be upgraded:
  fonts-opensymbol libreoffice libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer libreoffice-base libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-base-drivers libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw
  libreoffice-help-de libreoffice-impress libreoffice-java-common libreoffice-kde libreoffice-l10n-de libreoffice-math libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-report-builder-bin libreoffice-sdbc-firebird
  libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-style-oxygen libreoffice-writer python3-uno uno-libs3 ure
```

Please note, thought that right now the packages in the repo still carry the version tag rc3. It might take some more time until they are updated to the final version.

Answer (score 5):

The "official" PPA for Libre-Office 4.4:

https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/libreoffice-4-4

To add it:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

"et voilà"

Comment: The other advantage with this one, is that it is the STABLE release. Those going for the generic libreoffice/ppa need to realise it is the betas and alphas ppa, and thus often has unstable updates.

Answer (score 5):

LibreOffice 4.4 has been added to the official libreoffice ppa some hours ago.
You can update it right now:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

in case you don't have the ppa already, put this line into the terminal before.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no PPA named *libreoffice-4-4* on [LibreOffice's Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice).

Try to install using the following PPA -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-prereleases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

The *libreoffice-prereleases* PPA currently contains LibreOffice 4.4 packages.

Alternately, [download](http://dev-builds.libreoffice.org/pre-releases/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_4.4.0.1_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz) the `LibreOffice_4.4.0.1_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz` from the prereleases server. Extract it into a folder, `cd` into it and install using `sudo dpkg -i '*.deb'`.

Comment: only alpha and beta can be installed using sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-prereleases. How to install RC?

Comment: I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

link to latest *.deb packages:

https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/#change

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: Add the Official PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
```

Step 2: Update the Repository

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Step 3: Install Libreoffice 4.2.2

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```